# Reading values from php.ini by ini_get returns empty string

Tags: php, ini

1) Xampp is running on locally
2) I added administration_panel.cfg.database_host="localhost" to php.ini and restarted server
3) ini_get returns empty string

I don't know what i'm doing wrong :(
All i want to do is store connection data in php.ini :(

Do you know what i need to do to be able to read values from php.ini?

my php version is 5.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php.ini is to store PHP global settings, not custom configuration options.  Use a new ini file and use [**parse_ini_file**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) for a custom application config.